Xcode 15.4 / iOS app no info.plist, how to force light mode
I am building my first iOS app and I cannot find the info.plist in Xcode 15.4. I went to the project info and selected the target app and click on info but I cannot find any Appearance field of a way to add a new key.

Anybody have an idea? For now, I just want the app to run in .light mode
Thanks

If the app is SwiftUI, try setting .preferredColorScheme(.light) on a high-level view

The underlying property list key is UIUserInterfaceStyle, take a look at the documentation.
In the Info-view tap plus-sign(+) behind one of the keys, add UIUserInterfaceStyle as key and hit return. It will show as Appearance afterwards. Set the value to Light.
